# Prevent softkeyboard from pushing content up outside of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/fraga"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_input"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#DDD"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewQuestion"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:contentDescription="@string/image"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPrev"
    style="@style/white_button"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/tillbaka" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    style="@style/white_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonPrev"
    android:text="@string/nasta" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/layout_input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttonPrev"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:digits="0123456789(),.*-+/=:"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="@string/svar"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="28sp"
         >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i click the edittext the softkeyboard pops up and pushes the edittext to be just above the keyboard as expected. The only problem is that it also pushes the content above the edittext up. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: can you attach a screenshot too?

Comment: Sorry, i dont have enough reputation to add images.

Comment: just put it on some online pic servers and add the link here

Answer (score 3):

Use this piece of code in your `manifest.xml`, inside the `activity` tag.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Like this:

```
<activity
   android:label="activity_name"
   android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) for an explanation of `android:imeOptions`.